# relative import_module without knowing name of containing package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Suppose a package structured like this:

```
package/
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
```

`__main__.py` currently has something like

```
import argparse

from . import foo
from . import bar

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    foo.init_subparser(subparsers.add_parser('foo', help=foo.__doc__)
    bar.init_subparser(subparsers.add_parser('bar', help=bar.__doc__)
    ...
```

The real program has many more subcommand modules, so I want to make that less repetitive by switching to a loop with dynamic imports, something like

```
import argparse
import importlib

SUBCOMMANDS = ['foo', 'bar']

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    for cmd in SUBCOMMANDS:
        mod = importlib.import_module('.'+mod, 'package')  # XXX
        mod.init_subparser(subparsers.add_parser(cmd, help=mod.__doc__)
    ...
```

This works fine *but* now, at the point marked XXX in the second code fragment, I have to know and hardwire the name of the package, which is not necessary with `from . import module`.

So, the question is, how can I do these relative dynamic imports without having to embed the name of the package into my code?

2.x compatibility is not required.

Comment: Are you looking for [``__package__``](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__) or [``__name__``](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__name__)  perhaps?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried `__name__` and got errors like "No module named `__main__.foo`"; I didn't know `__package__` existed, but it does seem to work.  Make that an answer?